# Auto complete property in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I have noticed many times developers use like a quick key to generate properties but I can not find what that key is. Is there a list i can look at with all the short keys?. what i am referring to is like when you do

`Highlight method + F12` takes you to the reference (for example), there is one specifically that would help me a lot, the property auto complete it usually puts something like

`public int something`, and the color shows as green or something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done with snippets. The default snippet can be expanded by typing `prop` and then pressing TAB.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're seeing is [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).  If this visual is the green you're referring to, it's CodeRush:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

also, if intelisence is ever "not there", simply press control + space. Works in Netbeans and Visual Studio